# Laplace Transform's phase delay

Tags: laplace-transform

I have read this example about time shift  of Laplace Transform somewhere.

It used a unit step function that has been shifted along $x$ axis for $a$ unit. 
[image]

So, to find the Laplace Transform of it, we use the definition of Laplace Transform like this:

$\mathcal{L\{ u(t-a)\}}$ = $\int_0^\infty u(t-a)e^{-st} dt$

since the function has been shifted to the right by $a$ unit, $f(t) = 0$ for $t<a$. Thus integrating from $a$ to $\infty$.

$\int_a^\infty 1 e^{-st}dt = \frac{1}{-s}e^{-st}]_a^{-st} = \frac{1}{s} e^{-as}  $

I understand that $\frac{1}{s}$ being the result of $\mathcal{L\{ u(t)\}}$ and the extra term $e^{-st}$ is the result of time shift $-a$ . It is stated that this is true for all functions and not just for unit-step function , $u(t)$.

Soon after, I have come across this function, $f(t) = sin(\omega t+\theta)$. By comparing this function with the previous example, I thought the function has been shifted to the left by $\theta$ unit.

But since we are integrating only from 0 to $\infty$ in our Laplace Formula (we are dealing with time so I thought t can't be less than 0?),how do I approach this problem?

I am aware that we have this formula $sin(\omega t) = \frac{\omega}{s^2+\omega^2}$ and I also have the answer this problem. I just want to understand how to approach this problem conceptually.

**UPDATE:**

While Seyed provided a nice solution, I found out there is an easier way to get the result by doing some trigo manipulation.

I could expand $sin(\omega t + \theta)$ as $sin(\omega t)cos(\theta) + cos(\omega t)sin(\theta)$

By looking the Laplace transform of $sin(\omega t)$ and $cos(\omega t)$ from Laplace transform table, we could just simply substitute them into above equation without having to deal with Euler's formula.

Comment: Since you are dealing with an improper integral, consider substituting the $\infty$ with some parameter, say $t$, and then evaluate $\lim_{t \to \infty}\int_{0}^{t}f(t)e^{-st}dt$. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you should make a distinction between the functions ${f_1}(t) = \sin (\omega t + \theta )U(t)$ and ${f_2}(t) = \sin (\omega t + \theta )U(t - {t_0})$, specifically, the shift rules you mention apply to the totally shifted function (${f_2}(t)$) not ${f_1}(t)$. The most straight forward approach that I recommend to you for calculating the Laplace transform of a function is "Direct Integration", as you have noted. For example $$\begin{array}{l}\mathfrak{L}\{ \sin (\omega t + \theta )\}  = \int\limits_0^{ + \infty } {\sin (\omega t + \theta ){e^{ - st}}dt}  = \int\limits_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{e^{i(\omega t + \theta )}} - {e^{ - i(\omega t + \theta )}}}}{{2i}}{e^{ - st}}dt}  = \\\frac{{{e^{i\theta }}}}{{2i}}\int\limits_0^{ + \infty } {{e^{(i\omega  - s)t}}dt}  - \frac{{{e^{ - i\theta }}}}{{2i}}\int\limits_0^{ + \infty } {{e^{ - (i\omega  + s)t}}dt}  =  - \frac{1}{{2i}}\left( {\frac{{{e^{i\theta }}}}{{i\omega  - s}} + \frac{{{e^{ - i\theta }}}}{{i\omega  + s}}} \right) = \\\frac{1}{{2i}}\left( {\frac{{{e^{i\theta }}(i\omega  + s) + {e^{ - i\theta }}(i\omega  - s)}}{{{\omega ^2} + {s^2}}}} \right) = \frac{\omega }{{{\omega ^2} + {s^2}}}\left( {\frac{{{e^{i\theta }} + {e^{ - i\theta }}}}{2}} \right) + \frac{s}{{{\omega ^2} + {s^2}}}\left( {\frac{{{e^{i\theta }} - {e^{ - i\theta }}}}{{2i}}} \right) = \\\frac{\omega }{{{\omega ^2} + {s^2}}}\cos \theta  + \frac{s}{{{\omega ^2} + {s^2}}}\sin \theta \end{array}$$Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Not trying to be super picky, but is there a way to relate the Laplace transform of $sin(\omega t)$  to the Laplace transform of shifted function $sin(\omega t + \theta)$? While direct integration is straight forward, I am wondering if I could make use of the pre-calculated Laplace Transform of $sin(\omega t)$ to get the result.

Comment: @ChrisAung For the truly shifted function, we have $$\begin{array}{l}\mathfrak{L}\{ \sin (\omega (t - {t_0}))U(t - {t_0})\}  = \\\int\limits_0^\infty  {\sin (\omega (t - {t_0}))U(t - {t_0}){e^{ - st}}dt}  = \\\int\limits_{{t_0}}^\infty  {\sin (\omega (t - {t_0}))U(t - {t_0}){e^{ - st}}dt} \mathop  = \limits^{\tau  = t - {t_0}} \\{e^{ - s{t_0}}}\int\limits_0^\infty  {\sin (\omega \tau )U(t){e^{ - s\tau }}d\tau }  = \\{e^{ - s{t_0}}}\mathfrak{L}\{ \sin (\omega t)U(t)\} \end{array}$$

Comment: if that is the case, the Laplace transform of $sin(\omega t+\theta)$ ($\theta$ being $t_0$ ) should be equal to $e^{-\theta s} \frac{\omega}{s^2+\omega^2}$  given that Laplace transform of $sin(\omega t) = \frac{\omega}{s^2+\omega^2}$. Sorry for being a help vimpire, I am desperate to understand this.

Comment: @ChrisAung I want to emphasize that the critical point here is the delay in the step function, anyway if your function is something like $$\sin (\omega t - \theta )U(\omega t - \theta )$$(and $theta$ should be positive here), then the factor ${e^{ - \frac{\theta }{\omega }s}}$ will appear in the Laplace transform.

Comment: Thanks! I sort of understand it. If my step function is not being shifted, i won't be able to simply add $e^{-st_0}$ to the original Lapalce Transform. But if my step function is shifted the same amount as my function then I could add the $e^{-st_0}$ to the Laplace Transform of my original function without shift to get the final Transform.